# bat file doesn't proceed after mvn clean install

Tags: maven, batch-file

I've put below lines in a .bat file

`cd D:\code\MML\

cd D:\code\MML\com

svn update

mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

cd D:\code\MML\m14_6

svn update

mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

When I run this it can successfully change directories i.e. `cd D:\code\MML\`  and `cd D:\code\MML\com` get executed. However after maven clean install `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`(takes about 5 minutes to execute), it doesn't proceed further to execute `cd D:\code\MML\m14_6`

How can I fix this(tried to search, but keywords put in by me is not fetching the answer I need) ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try `cd /D D:\code\MML\m14_6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a command file from a running command file you need to CALL it, if not the current running command file will not resume. Try :

```
call mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...I was not aware of call